# NodeJs Decode to readable text

Tags: node.js

**PROBLEM**

I want to receive data from a device using IP Address via NodeJs. But I received the following data:

[image: funny characters]

**What I've Tried**

This is the code that I've been able to get, which still produces the problem I described above.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var url = require('url') ;
var statusCode = 200;

app.listen(6565);

function handler (req, res) {
 var data = '';

req.on('data', function(chunk) {
  data += chunk;
});

req.on('end', function() {
console.log(data.toString());
fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFile('helloworld.txt', data.toString(), function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});
});

res.writeHead(statusCode, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end();
}
```

And below is the result I received for console.log(req.headers)

[image: req.headers console]

So my question is, how do I decode the data? and anyone know what type of data are they?

Comment: Your program is working just fine. The data being sent needs to be sorted out. Can you help us with an example data?

Comment: do you mean example data sent from device? The manufacturer didn't gave it. Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: What does `console.log(res.headers)` show inside `handler()`?

Comment: Yes, I meant that, @AmalinaAziz. Do you know what kind of request object you are receiving? Please write the request object.

Comment: i got undefined. @mscdex

Comment: @AakashVerma how to do so? any references?

Comment: @AmalinaAziz Sorry, I meant `req.headers`.

Comment: Haha , this has been a problem for me and almost everyone. I was hoping that somehow I could send the request object as a whole as the response but was unable to do so. Read my exact problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251553/node-js-request-object-documentation)

Comment: But yes, what does `console.log(req.headers)` say?

Comment: Might be useful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672997/how-to-read-content-type-application-octet-stream-request-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

Use `Buffers` to handle octet streams.

```
function handler (req, res) {

    let body=[];

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
    });


     req.on('end', function() {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString('utf8');
    ...
```

Comment: Try this and let me know  :/

Comment: `chunk` is already a Buffer. Also, `Buffer.concat` requires an array of Buffer instances, not a single one, and should really be called in the `end` handler.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks a lot! I have got so rusty.

Comment: Lastly: because the response is `application/octet-stream`, it's likely to be a binary format, so calling `toString()` on it may mangle it (however, it seems that OP doesn't know what the format of the data is, so it may be _anything_).

Comment: @AmalinaAziz Why are you suggesting that edit? Did the previous one work for you?

Comment: @AakashVerma missing ). but the buffer one didn't work.

Comment: @robertklep Isn't toString() actually specified by the Buffer class to do that? I agree that the encoding is optional.

Comment: @AakashVerma with `toString()`, you're telling Node to try and convert the binary data to a (UTF-8-encoded) string, but it may not be a string, or UTF-8-encoded, at all.

Comment: @AmalinaAziz what exactly isn't working? We can't help you with decoding the data properly if you don't know what it actually is.

Comment: @robertklep Okay but if we are able to get a string representation of it, we can later know what to do. Aziz doesn't know what data format or what data he is receiving.

Comment: @AakashVerma in that case, you want to use `toString('binary')`, so Node will not try to convert it to UTF-8.